# Paint.NET style ToolWindow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Can anyone tell me how to make Paint.NET style ToolWindow(s)? Sorry I don't know if there is some kind of terminology to describe this better.

Currently my ToolWindows take focus whenever I click on a control inside of the ToolWindow or the ToolWindow itself. This means that if I click on the ToolBar or the MenuBar in the main form of my program that only bring the form into focus and doesn't actually click on the ToolBar / Menu. I don't want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can donwload source code od Paint.NET and look how implemented "ToolWindows".

[download page](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/paint.net.cfm)

Comment: I had been looking for that but they removed it from the Paint.NET website. Thanks a lot.